# Adding Materials using Image Texture

Tags: materials, uv, node-editor, transparency, image

What am i doing wrong here.
I select the faces that i require
[image]

I assign them to a new material
[image]
Unwrap the UV
[image]
Save as an SVG
[image]
Make a template, obviously i dont want square corners so some parts of my template go inside the UV SVG
[image]
Save as a PNG, Use an image texture to add the graphic, but the square parts that i rounded off and were not part of the PNG are now actually transparent not just black. If i remove the Alpha then the unused pixels are black.
[image]

Comment: Perhaps a silly question, but what would you like to have in the square parts ? As these are not in the imported PNG (i.e. these are *empty*), what default value/colour/texture are you expecting from Blender ?

Comment: Each face can only have a single material assigned. When you assign the material with the blue stripe, then there is no other material on this face - therefore it has nothing to show "underneath" where the transparent parts are. What you have to do instead is create a material which has the blue and green mixed by using the alpha channel as mix factor (in this case inverted). When you only want a color there, you actually just need a black & white image of the mask and a _Mix Color_ node where one color is blue and the other green.

Comment: I dont want anything in the square parts, i just have to select these and then round off the edges when making the template from the UV map because when we make the stickers the corners are not square, If you see the 3rd picture from the top the bike has graphics on, somebody else made the template, i am just trying to figure out how to do it.

Comment: I have an image of exactly what i am trying to achieve but how do i upload another image?